# show only row which is not in joined table

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have three tables - class, section, class_section.

**class**

[image: class]

**section**

[image: section]

**class_section**

[image: class-section]

I can't show row/rows which is not in joined table. For example, while analyzing above joined table (`c_id` refers to `class_id`, `s_id` refers to `section_id`)`class_section` table, class **One** (`c_id=1`) has section **B** (`s_id=2`). Now while checking class one checkbox, it has to show only class **A**, because it has not inserted. In summary, I am trying to show `section name` which has not assigned to class, it mean which is not in `class_section` table.I can't manage three tables. I tried a lot, but thought following code was near to result, still doesn't work

```
"SELECT section.id, section.en_title, class_section.c_id, class_section.s_id FROM section JOIN class_section ON class_section.s_id = section.id WHERE section.id != class_section.s_id AND class_section.c_id=:id"
    $result->bindparam(':id',$_POST['id']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this sql query for your problem.

```
SELECT class.en_title AS class_name, section.en_title AS section_name FROM class
    INNER JOIN section LEFT JOIN class_section ON 
    (class_section.c_id = class.id AND class_section.s_id = section.id) 
    WHERE class_section.id IS NULL
```